# I am trying to get newly attached disk (Pen Drive) MOUNT POINT in MAC OS with C code

Tags: c, xcode, macos, mount-point, diskarbitration

I am new to MAC OS X. I want to get **Mount Point** of **newly attached disk (Pen Drive)**. I already tried some code and got mount path from **command**

> diskutil info disk1S2 | grep \" Mount Point: \" | awk '{print $3}'

where **disk1S2** is **Identifier** of newly attached disk.

But I want to get mount point from C code **without depending upon command**.

So tried this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
#include  <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h> 
#include  <DiskArbitration/DASession.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define MAXPATHLEN 500

void hello_disk(DADiskRef disk, void *context){
    CFDictionaryRef diskinfo,dict;
    diskinfo = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
    CFURLRef fspath = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict,&kDADiskDescriptionVolumePathKey);
    char buf[MAXPATHLEN];
    if (CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(fspath, false, (UInt8 *)buf, sizeof(buf))) {
        printf("Disk %s mounted at %s\n",DADiskGetBSDName(disk),buf);
        // Print the complete dictionary for debugging. 
        CFShow(diskinfo);
    }else {
        // Something is *really* wrong. /
    }
}

void goodbye_disk(DADiskRef disk, void *context){
    printf("disk %s disappeared\n", DADiskGetBSDName(disk));
}

int main(){
    DASessionRef session;

    session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);

    DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, NULL, hello_disk, NULL);
    DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback(session, NULL, goodbye_disk, NULL);

    DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(session,CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    CFRelease(session);
    exit(0);
}
```

and I run this code by this command

> gcc DAD.c -o DAD -framework DiskArbitration -framework Foundation

but I am getting this error

> Segmentation fault: 11

- Why I am getting this error ?
- How can I get mount point in MAC OS ?